# Linux command to download file from server to remote desktop

Tags: linux, remote-desktop

I use windows remote desktop and work on a remote session. I connect to a server, I would like to download a file which is on the server and copy it to the (remote) desktop to be able to look at it and modify it in notepad.

Is it possible, and is there a command line for this ?

-- Windows keyboard system, windows remote desktop, linux server

Comment: Did you try wget

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Windows Remote Desktop to copy files from remote to local PC or vice versa, [using RDClip and the clipboard or by drag-and-drop](https://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-copy-and-paste-files-across-remote-desktop/).

Though I haven't tried it, *copy* and *robocopy* should also work.

That said, you might *not* be able to access the C:, i.e., root, folder using Remote Desktop, unless running as Administrator.